# Sencha touch calendar swarmonline - refresh calendar event

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm trying to work with a Sencha Touch calendar extension (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?156351-Ext.ux.TouchCalendar) Here is an example of what im using: http://www.swarmonline.com/Ext.ux.TouchCalendar/examples/simple-events-list.html

Am facing a problem here. when the app loads first time the events dots are missing..but when I resize my browser window, suddenly some event call happens and dots become visible and also at the same time its duplicating..

Am using their Simple events plugin. This is my view structure

```
Ext.define('WinReo.view.EventListPanel', {

    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    //xtype:'EventListPanel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.dataview.List',
        'Ext.layout.Fit'

    ],

    alias: 'widget.EventListPanel',

    config: {
        // title   : 'Events List',
        layout  : 'fit',
        store:'WinReo.store.Events'
    },

    initialize: function(){



        var store = Ext.getStore('Events');
        store.load({
            callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                // the operation object contains all of the details of the load operation
                console.log(records);
            },
            scope: this
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.setItems([

            {
                xclass      : 'Ext.ux.TouchCalendarView',
                itemId      : 'calendarView',
                //minDate     : Ext.Date.add((new Date()), Ext.Date.DAY, -40),
                //maxDate     : Ext.Date.add((new Date()), Ext.Date.DAY, 55),

                viewMode    : 'month',
                weekStart   : 0,
                value       : new Date(),
                eventStore  : Ext.getStore('Events'),
                plugins     : [Ext.create('Ext.ux.TouchCalendarSimpleEvents')]
                /* plugins     : [Ext.create('Ext.ux.TouchCalendarEvents', {
                 eventBarTpl: '{Days2Go}'
                 })]*/
            },

            {

                xtype       : 'list',
                itemId      : 'calendarlist',
                docked      : 'bottom',
                onItemDisclosure:'true',
                cls:'myList',
                height      : 100,
                itemTpl     : ['<tpl if ="Days2Go==0">',
                    '<div class="calendarlistred"> <div style="float:left; width: 45%">{PropertyAddr}</div><div style="float:left; width:45%">{TaskDesc}</div><div style="float:right; width:10%">{Days2Go}</div></div>',
                    '</tpl>',
                    '<tpl if ="Days2Go!=0">',
                    '<div> <div style="float:left; width: 45%">{PropertyAddr}</div><div style="float:left; width:45%">{TaskDesc}</div><div style="float:left; width:10%">{Days2Go}</div></div>',
                    '</tpl>'
                ],
                store       : Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    model: 'WinReo.model.Event',
                    data: []
                }),

                listeners: {
                    itemtap: function(dw, index,record, item, e){

                        window.open('http://blr.amt.in:8081/CRM_API/TaskCalendar.ashx?all_tasks=-1');

                    }
                }
            },
            {
                xtype      : 'label',
                html: '<div> <div style="float:left; width: 45%">Property</div><div style="float:left; width:45%">Task Description</div><div style="float:right; width:10%">Days to go</div></div>',
                layout:'hbox',
                docked      : 'bottom',
                cls:'calendarlistheader'


            }


        ]);


    }

});
```

Also I want I come to know that there is function there in TouchCalendarSimpleEvents.js

```
  refreshEvents: function(){
    if (!this.disabled && this.calendar.getViewMode() !== ‘DAY’) {
    var datesStore = this.calendar.getStore();
    …..

how can i call this function in my periodchange controller event ? 
onPeriodChange: function(view, minDate, maxDate, direction){

    Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders({
        'session_id' : localStorage.getItem("session_id")
    });

    console.log('periodchange');
    console.log(view);
    console.log(minDate);
    var monthstartdate = Ext.Date.format(minDate, 'm/d/Y');
    var url = 'http://blr.amt.in:8081/CRM_API/TaskCalendar.ashx?';
    var urlafter = url + 'monthstartdate='+ monthstartdate;
    // proxy change
    var group_store = Ext.getStore("Events");
    group_store.getProxy().setUrl(urlafter);
    group_store.load();
    var storecount = group_store.getCount();
    this.refreshEvents(); // ***here i want to call refresh function***


}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: that control bums me out.  it is fantastic, but littered with bugs that make it unusable.  I can't get it to work right in 2.1.  If you go to their extensions page it just hoards of comments picking out problems.  I hope they keep refining it, but until it's stable I can't build an application using it.

Comment: its working fine for me.. i have managed to solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058053/secha-touch-calendar-swarmonline-mvc-bug