# secha touch calendar swarmonline mvc bug

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm trying to work with a Sencha Touch calendar extension (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?156351-Ext.ux.TouchCalendar) Here is an example of what im using: http://www.swarmonline.com/Ext.ux.TouchCalendar/examples/simple-events-list.html

Am using the mvc folder in the app.. there is bug in period change event
please follow these steps

1. load mvc app
2. click event list

3 click any date that have event

4 Then click period change

5 Rest of the events are gone from the calendar

Am trying hard to fix this issue.. please help me solve it.. your help is much appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: I am addressing this issue in the GitHub repo (https://github.com/SwarmOnline/Ext.ux.TouchCalendar/issues/19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the quick reply...Yes i am using touch calendar simple events, that will call each moth events in separate period change..My problem is solved.. I dont know what was issue i just refresth the touchcalendarview in period change. Then all the dots are coming as expected..Thanks for the help dear..This plugin is really awesome.. Its rally helped me in my current project...

this is what i did in my period change function

```
onPeriodChange: function(view, minDate, maxDate, direction){
        var monthstartdate = Ext.Date.format(minDate, 'm/d/Y');
        var url = 'http://test.example.in:8081/CRM_API/TaskCalendar.ashx?';
        var urlafter = url + 'monthstartdate='+ monthstartdate;
        var group_store = Ext.getStore("Events");
        group_store.getProxy().setUrl(urlafter);
        group_store.load(function(){

            Ext.getCmp('touchcalendarview').refresh();
        });

}
```

Once again thanks for the help...